# Not able to insert Json values into json column of my table through postman

Tags: json, laravel, postman

Here is my item table(laravel migration):

```
Schema::connection('mysql')->create('item', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsignedInteger();
            $table->unsignedInteger('icd');
            $table->unsignedInteger('itypeid');
            $table->json('mandatory_prop');
            $table->unsignedInteger('parentId')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('icd')->references('id')->on('itemClass')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('itypeid')->references('id')->on('itemType')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('parentId')->references('id')->on('item')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Here is the error :
[link to error message picture in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0QcL.jpg)

**Route:**

```
   Route::post('item','ItemController@store');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
    //input a new role
    $item = $request->isMethod('put') ? Item::findOrFail($request->item_id) : new Item;
    $item->id = $request->input('item_id');
    $item->icd = $request->input('icd');
    $item->itypeId = $request->input('itypeId');
    $item->mandatory_prop = $request->input('mandatory_prop');
    $item->parentId = $request->input('parentId');

     if($item->save()) {
       return new itemResource($item);
       }
  }
```

Comment: Can you give your controller code here ?

Comment: Yes i hav posted the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Add this in your `Item Model`

```
protected $casts = [
     'mandatory_prop' => 'json',
];
```

And `$request->input('mandatory_prop')` is must be **Array**

you can use `$request->input('mandatory_prop')` or `$request->mandatory_prop`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the image, your problem doesn't seems to be the json column, but the `icd` column which turns out to be `null` instead of the value 2 that you are passing. Make sure That in your `Item` model you have listed the `icd` column in your `fillable` array.

And then for the JSON, you use wrong quotes to distinguish the key or the string. So try:

```
"mandatory_prop": "{'size': '35mb', 'Speed': '2.86Hz'}"
```

You can even try without the `""` around the json object.